# Middleware does not work on previous page

Tags: express, authentication, routes, back-button, express-session

I have a middleware on express.js, that the user can access to certain routes only if he is logged or not. The problem appears when i click the button previous page , the middleware does not work.

```
app.get('/',isNotLogged,(req, res) => {

 res.render('main.hbs',{
    empty: req.flash('empty'),
    error: req.flash('error')
 })
})
```

And this is the middleware

```
const isNotLogged = (req, res, next) => {

const login = req.session.userId;

if (login) {
    
    return res.redirect('/home')
}
next();
}
```

The middleware works properly if i try to access to the route by the navigation bar, but if i clicked the "back button" on the browser, it doesn´t work.

Comment: watch the network tab in hour browser and check whether there’s request done with the back button or not .

Comment: no, there´s no request done on the back button